# Why is my Angular route to invoke a component not working?

Tags: angular

I have the following route in AppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'subjects',
    loadChildren: () => import('./subjects/subjects.module').then(m =>
    m.SubjectsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'subject',
    loadChildren: () => import('./subjects/subjects.module').then(m =>
      m.SubjectsModule)
  },
]
```

And the following in SubjectsModule (note, the first route here is to SubjectsComponent not SubjectComponent. It works. The second route is what's failing.):

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: 'get/:grade/:gradeLabel',
   component: SubjectsComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'gradeLabel/:gradeLabel/subjectId/:subjectId',
   component: SubjectComponent
 },
  ];
```

And the following link to SubjectComponent:

```
<!-- <a class="login" *ngFor="let subject of subjects"
        [routerLink]="['/subject', 'gradeLabel', gradeLabel, 'subjectId', subject._id]">
        <h1>{{subject.name}}</h1>
    </a> -->

    <a class="login" *ngFor="let subject of subjects"
        routerLink="/subject/gradeLabel/{{gradeLabel}}/subjectId/{{subject._id}}">
        <h1>{{subject.name}}</h1>
    </a>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
main.8c91e83820883126.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002
Error: NG04002
at ga.noMatchError
```

However, a call to this path pasting the below URL directly in the browser works:

```
http://localhost:4200/subject/gradeLabel/Grade%209/subjectId/63e2739b3dad93238da85918
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Subject router, for the SubjectComponent route, remove the slash before gradeLabel.

```
 {
   path: 'gradeLabel/:gradeLabel/subjectId/:subjectId',
   component: SubjectComponent
 },
```

so your path goes from path: '/gradeLabel......' to path: 'gradeLabel....'

Comment: That's an oversight on my part but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I would also stick with using the format of [routerlink]=[.....] that you have commented out.  It usually helps me stay away from simple mistakes.  Another thing I try when running into routing issues is moving the path to the top of your router module.  so your gradelabel {} moved above the { path: 'get/:grade ...} path entry. Some times order matters

Comment: Changed the order, used [routerLink] syntax, still didn't work.  However when I paste the url directly in the browser, it works. http://localhost:4200/subject/gradeLabel/Grade%209/subjectId/63e2739b3dad93238da85918

Comment: in your approuting module, is the subject route a child route?  can you paste the full approuting module?

Comment: I have augmented my question to show the relevant part of AppRoutingModule. It is shown in the first segment of my question.

Comment: Another thing to debug, update your app component router module with this to enable tracing (console logs): 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      enableTracing: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

Comment: I am also assuming your appcomponent.html has the  <router-outlet> tag

Comment: Yes, router outlet is in place.